# ogr.CoordinateTransformation appears to be inverting xy coordinates

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, osgeo, osr

My problem exists with Polygons, but I created the following as an example using points to simplify my problem. My issue is when transforming geometry from EPSG:26913 to EPSG:4326 the output of x and y are swapped. For example, using https://epsg.io/ If I start with the 26913 coordinates 351415.75 3885929.09
[image]

And then convert to 4326, I get the expected POINT (-106.630305974043 35.1052340446701)

[image]

If I run this code below, I would expect the output POINT (-106.630305974043 35.1052340446701),
but instead, I get the output POINT (35.1052340446701 -106.630305974043)

```
from osgeo import ogr,osr

source = osr.SpatialReference()
source.ImportFromEPSG(26913)

target = osr.SpatialReference()
target.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source, target)

point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt("POINT (351415.75 3885929.09)")
point.Transform(transform)

print(point.ExportToWkt())
#Output: POINT (35.1052340446701 -106.630305974043)
```

The points are transformed, but they are inverted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Officially EPSG:4326 is using latitude-longitude order. There is an option to use the traditional GIS order https://gdal.org/api/ogrspatialref.html `OGR_CT_FORCE_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER configuration option can be set to YES`.

Comment: That did it. For anyone interested I just added target.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)  before creating the transformation. How do I accept the answer above?

Comment: Please write the answer yourself with complete working code and I will give you a vote.

Comment: @user30184 So does OGR_CT_FORCE_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER get used only for 4326 or can this be used with all EPSG ids?

Comment: It can be used with all EPSG ids and it converts the coordinate order into lon-lat or easting-northing if the native order of the CRS is lat-lon or northing-easting. It does not flip the axis of CRSs which use lon-lat or E-N by definition.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from user30184 was correct.

Adding `target.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)` after importing the SR from an EPSG code gave me the desired output!
Here is the example code I posted before, showing how it is used.

```
from osgeo import ogr,osr
source = osr.SpatialReference()
source.ImportFromEPSG(26913)
target = osr.SpatialReference()
target.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

#The line below sets the TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER that I was expecting.
target.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)

transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source, target)
point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt("POINT (351415.75 3885929.09)")
point.Transform(transform)
print(point.ExportToWkt())
#New Output: POINT (-106.630305974043 35.1052340446701)
```